# Missing disc space on Ubuntu Hardy

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04

I have a Dell Mini 10 running Ubuntu Hardy.

I ran out of disk space; looking at Disk Analyzer I noticed that in addition to the standard /dev/sda2 filesystem, there was a second called gfvs-fuse-daemon, each with 50% [5.9G] of my available disc space [11.8G]. Reading around a bit, it seems that gvfs has decided a network drive is in fact a root partition

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simplebackup/+bug/227753

I unmounted gvfs-fuse-daemon, which removed it from the partition list but unfortunately didn't free up the 5.9G - I think it's somehow 'hidden' and would like it back as I am chronically short of space.

I'm certain this is related to plugging in a badly- formatted USB drive a couple of weeks ago. Reading the following

[No free disk space](https://serverfault.com/questions/132998/no-free-disk-space)

[Out of disk space on 4GB partiton yet it's only using 2GB](https://serverfault.com/questions/122894/out-of-disk-space-on-4gb-partiton-yet-its-only-using-2gb)

it sounds like there may be a hidden file somewhere which needs deleting

I have run 'tune2fs -m 1 /var/sda2' to maximise what little space I have

Any assistance in cleaning up this mess would be gratefully received.

Thank you.

---

jhw@jhw:~$ fdisk -l /dev/sda
Cannot open /dev/sda
jhw@jhw:~$ fdisk -l /dev/sda2
Cannot open /dev/sda2

---

jhw@jhw:~$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              6123552   5517260    543080  92% /
varrun                  512456       100    512356   1% /var/run
varlock                 512456         0    512456   0% /var/lock
udev                    512456        44    512412   1% /dev
devshm                  512456        12    512444   1% /dev/shm
lrm                     512456      1652    510804   1% /lib/modules/2.6.24-27 
lpia/volatile

---

jhw@jhw:~$ lsof +L1
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NLINK  NODE NAME
firefox 5438  jhw   37u   REG    8,2 1544     0 97221 /var/tmp/etilqs_WxQgt6n5lgV3QoI (deleted)
firefox 5438  jhw   38u   REG    8,2 1024     0 98379 /var/tmp/etilqs_fkODKeKm4ZOazIo (deleted)
firefox 5438  jhw   55u   REG    8,2    0     0 98402 /var/tmp/etilqs_GUbgrLdlbap3xK7 (deleted)
jhw@jhw:~$

Comment: the output from the following commands may help: `fdisk -l /dev/sda`; `df`; (as indicated in the threads you cite) `lsof +L1`.

Comment: The size of the root filesystem is about 6GB, and it's 92% full. Maybe the `/dev/sda2` doesn't fill the whole disk. You need to run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` as root; this will show how your disk is partitioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-installed gvfs-fuse-daemon and the offending partition has re-appeared; I'm going to open a new question relating to gvfs-fuse-daemon