# Process unable to write file - disk space ran out what happened?

Tags: nginx, filesystems, file-permissions, disk-space-utilization

I had a situation with a server misconfig. Nginx was unable to write its logs due to invalid file permissions and checking with `free` the buffers/caches were at about 3.2GB (out of 4GB Memory).

Nginx master process was able to write logs - but the child processes could not open the logs. (Nginx error log revealed this)

The system failed because it ran out of disk space (checked syslog). However, just before it failed disk space checked with `df` was plentiful.

What's the underlying explanation for this?

Comment: you are probably ran out of *inodes*: https://www.tecmint.com/check-inodes-in-linux/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Out of disk space on 4GB partiton yet it's only using 2GB](https://serverfault.com/questions/122894/out-of-disk-space-on-4gb-partiton-yet-its-only-using-2gb)